# make array_unique working for stop for each from repetition

Tags: php

I have three for each loop all that are unnecessary

```
<?php foreach($Categories as $Category){ ?>

<div id="accordion" data-accordion="" class="left_sub_menu">
        <h3 class="accordion"><?=$Category['category_name']?></h3>              
            <div class="panel">
                <ul>
                <?php foreach($Category['Product_name'] as $product){ ?>
                <?php foreach($Category['Product_slug'] as $slug){ ?>
                <?php // $product = array_unique($product['name']); ?> 

                <li><a href="<?=Base_url()?>products/<?=$slug?>" ><?=$product;?></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php  } ?>
                </ul>
            </div>      
<?php } ?>
```

but $products repeats how to stop it from repeating please help

The input array is:

```
[0] => Array (
    [category_name] =>Starting System
    [category_id] => 5
    [ Product_slug] => Array (
        [0] => starting_system
        [1] => pow-r-quik_air
        [2] => gali_air
        [3] => hydraulic_starter
        ....
        [8] => spring_starter
    )
    [Product_name] => Array (
        [0] => Starting System
        [1] => Pow-R-Quik Air
        [2] => Gali Air
        ...
        [8] => Spring Starter
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: If you can provide what data comes in the arrays and what is your expected outcome, it would be easy to help you.

Comment: can you show us the output of `echo "<pre/>";print_r($Categories);`?  if it's big then not the complete data but post 2 indexes data

Comment: Dont loop foreach in foreach. Build you array as per your view. It will help you for easy traversal

Comment: [0] => Array ( [category_name] =>Starting System [category_id] => 5 [ Product_slug] => Array ( [0] => starting_system  [1] => pow-r-quik_air  [2] => gali_air  [3] => hydraulic_starter[4] => diesel_engine_safety [5] => mechanical_spring[6] => dual_starting_system  [7] => 3g_electric_starter [8] => spring_starter )[Product_name] => Array  (  [0] =>  Starting System [1] => Pow-R-Quik Air  [2] => Gali Air [3] =>  Hydraulic Starter [4] => Diesel Engine Safety[5] => Mechanical Spring [6] => Dual Starting System [7] => 3G Electric Starter [8] => Spring Starter )  )

Comment: how @Nishant please help

Comment: @meow how are you constructing the array? i tried it on my end to print it unable to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the number of "slugs" = products, you can just do a for loop around them.

(Note - there are better answers and code could be improved a lot, but this is the simplest to get you going.)

```
<?php foreach($Categories as $Category){ ?>

<div id="accordion" data-accordion="" class="left_sub_menu">
        <h3 class="accordion"><?=$Category['category_name']?></h3>              
            <div class="panel">
                <ul>
                <?php for ($i=0; $i < count($Category['Product_name']); ++$i)){ ?>
                <?php $product = $Category['Product_name'][$i]; ?> 
                <?php $slug = $Category['Product_slug'][$i]; ?> 

                <li><a href="<?=Base_url()?>products/<?=$slug?>" ><?=$product;?></a></li>
                <?php  } ?>
                </ul>
            </div>      
<?php } ?>
```

---

Edit: Just a quick re-write of the code. Makes it clearer what's going on which will help debug that missing `</div>` you've got.

```
<?php
$output = '';

foreach($Categories as $Category) {
    $numItems = count($Category['Product_name']);

    $output .= '

    <div id="accordion" data-accordion="" class="left_sub_menu">
        <h3 class="accordion">' . htmlspecialchars($Category['category_name']) . '</h3>              
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>';

    for ($i=0; $i < $numItems; ++$i) {
        if (isset($Category['Product_slug'][$i])) {
            $output .= '<li><a href="' . Base_url() . 'products/' . htmlspecialchars(urlencode($Category['Product_slug'][$i])) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($Category['Product_name'][$i]) . '</a></li>';
        }
    }

    $output .= '
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>';      
}

echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: Welcome. I can see you're also new, so I've quickly given a re-write. Not perfect but it's getting rid of all those <?php tags which makes debugging and reading very hard. Also makes it clearer how you'll handle it when you have zero items, or how to debug when number slugs don't match the number of names etc.